# Automating screenshot workflow

Tags: applescript, automator, preview, screen-capture

I am looking for a way to launch Preview on my Mac automatically, whenever I take a screenshot to my clipboard. I use "cmd + shift + 4" most of the times, then open preview, then hit "cmd+n" which accomplishes what I'm after, but is just time-consuming.
I have looked around but haven't found an option to do this with Automator. I'm not sure if it's even possible that Automator 'monitors' the clipboard and whenever it receives a screenshot, could trigger Preview.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: By default **⌃⇧⌘4** is used to copy picture of selected area to the clipboard, did you change it to **⇧⌘4**? What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: Monitoring the clipboard is possible, but a ballache.  Would be much easier to create a new keyboard shortcut that triggers an Automator workflow to take the screenshot and then open it in Preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open /System/Applications/Utilities/Screenshot.app, you will be given the option to choose where your screenshot goes.    You can select for the screenshot to automatically open in Preview.

[image]

Now anytime you use your keyboard shortcuts to take a screenshot,  the default action would be to open the screenshot in Preview.

[image]

Comment: Depends on what version of macOS as the feature you mention is not in **macOS High Sierra** and earlier. It's also why I asked the OP what version of macOS he's running.

Comment: Thanks a ton @James. Absolute game changer for me!